# Vercel not deploying

Tags: javascript, npm, vercel, next.js13, swc

ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for @next/swc-win32-x64-msvc@13.4.12: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    win32
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  x64
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2023-08-23T07_11_39_411Z-debug-0.log
Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1

I was trying to deploy my web application project and it gave me this issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is what it has been showing me when trying to deploy from vercel.

Comment: [09:28:57.701] Previous build cache not available
[09:28:58.361] Cloning completed: 895.627ms
[09:28:58.805] Running "vercel build"
[09:28:59.303] Vercel CLI 32.0.1
[09:28:59.564] Installing dependencies...
[09:29:00.133] npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
[09:29:00.134] npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for @next/swc-win32-x64-msvc@13.4.12: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
[09:29:00.151] Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1